# How to iterate through LinkedHashMap to the xth element?

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

What is the best way to iterate through a LinkedHashMap to the xth element ?

```
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : existingFile.entrySet() )
            {

                builder.append("{" + entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue() + "}   ");

            }
```

This iterates to through all the elements, how can I stop it say at the 5th element ?

Comment: Either fetch the iterator directly and then use a `for` loop with an `int` iteration variable, or keep a counter that you increment within the enhanced for loop...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a counter:

```
int counter = 0;

for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : existingFile.entrySet() )
{
    if (counter == 5)
        break;

    builder.append("{" + entry.getKey() + "," + entry.getValue() + "}   ");
    counter++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

With Java 8 you can create a stream and limit it to 5 items:

```
existingFile.entrySet().stream()
     .limit(5)
     .forEach(e -> builder.append("{"
          + e.getKey() + "," 
          + e.getValue() + "}   "));
```